# how monolith spring 3 application will communicate with microservice?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-ribbon

I have one monolith spring web application developed using spring 3.1 and spring-security 3.1 with Java 7 and it is deployed on tomcat 7.

Now I have a new requirement where I have to create a micro-service for a new module using spring boot with java 8. This micro-service will be deployed separately on different EC2 instance.

I am looking for suggestion/idea to access new microservice from my existing spring web application.

How to perform *inter process communication* within these two spring application?

Can someone provide me any help/pointer?

Comment: Use something tried and tested: HTTP.

Comment: You mean i need to write rest client for each controller of microservices?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of service discovery pattern, which are mainly of two kinds -

1. Client-side discovery - This is where clients are responsible for figuring out available service instances. Example - Netflix OSS.
2. Server-side discovery - In this the service instances are registered on the server-side using a service registry. Example - AWS ELB.

You can read a lot about these on the internet. Just remember the keywords.
Hope this helps !